# New SQL Server user failed to login

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've created new user in SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008 Express) in security tab.

Specified the login name, SQL Server authentication, entered a password, assigned server role `sysadmin`, mapped to my database and there specify it as `db_owner`. Also in database security is specified in tab Schemas owned by this user is `db_owner`.

I've checked a lot of tutorials but all of them do the same as me but when I try to login to SQL server (even manually) error message is thrown:

> *Login failed for 'MyUser' (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)*

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Peter

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

Failed to login SQL Server after installing SQL Server and creating new login user for SQL Server? You can **check error description in Error Log file** at first. Look for entry and then confirm what "**State**" means in entry.

After making sure which lead to this SQL Server login error, take appropriate measures. Generally, you would need to do according to different situations.

1. You would need to change authentication mode to Mix Authentication or SQL Server Authentication mode.
2. You would have to enable SQL login user if the login is disabled.
3. Reset SQL Server user password if the login user password is incorrect.
4. Configure Windows Firewall to allow SQL Server access if the login is valid but server access is failed. 
   More details about fixing failed login error for user, you can refer to this article. 
   http://www.isunshare.com/sql-server/fix-sql-server-failed-login-error.html

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and solved mine by changing the Server to Mixed Authentication Mode. In my case, I was trying to log in with a SQL server login, but the server was only set up to accept Windows Authentication.

See this link for how to change it:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332

I realise this question is old, but I hope the answer helps someone.

Thanks