# user login failed for sql server user

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

I am getting below error while connecting sql server 2012 express with asp.net/C#.I am able to login in sql server management studio with same user and password but when I used it in connection string then I am getting below error.

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Login failed for user 'user'

My connection string is

```
 <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Initial  Catalog=sgweblog;Provider=SQLOLEDB;User Id=user;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258737/new-sql-server-user-failed-to-login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you read the error message? the login failed. your connection string is almost fine, you are probably specifying the wrong instance of the DB. try using the localhost\SQLEXPRESS since express editions install under the "SQLEXPRESS" named instance.

but again, remember - it could may well be, as the error message is said, that the username and password is incorrect.

did you try using trusted connection and see if that works?

"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=true;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseHere"

```
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=true;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseHere" />
```

Comment: thank you so much bro its working fine but one more query.its working on one place but if I put it same connection string in my main website then it is giving error like System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.

Comment: you should mark this is an answer. did you use the connection string EXACTLY as I provided it here?

Comment: I used this one after your suggestion and its giving me keyword 'Provider' error                                        <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial  Catalog=YourDatabaseHere;;Provider=SQLOLEDB;User Id=user;Password=password">

Comment: This is not what I suggested...take a look carefully.

Comment: what error are you getting? and why are you using provider-sqloledb? don't use this key string.

Comment: I used below connection string and its working now    <add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=true;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=user;Password=password"/>

Comment: God I feel stupid.. I KNEW I was running two instances of SQL Server but I still somehow overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.use  `Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS`

```
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial  Catalog=sgweblog;Provider=SQLOLEDB;User Id=user;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

[Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/)

Comment: Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sgweblog;User Id=user;Password=password;Provider=sqloledb

Comment: Make sure the SQL services are running and check your login,password credentials

Comment: Using the credentials found in the ConnectionString settings file, try to log in to the SQL server using Management Studio.

Comment: @vim System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.

Comment: @Nagraj Login credential are correct as I am able to login with same user in sql server management only this provider error are coming

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @vim try this Integrated Security=SSPI

Comment: Login credential are correct as I am able to login with same user in sql server management only this provider error are coming

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your Authentication type for SQL

IF You Using Windows Authentication , See this

[How To: Connect to SQL Server Using Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx)

IF You Using SQL Server Authentication , See this

[How To: Connect to SQL Server Using SQL Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx)